# Source code of keyboard driver of linux

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, linux-device-driver, kernel-module

I have been working on making my own keyboard driver for linux. So I came accross these two links: [usbkbd.c](http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/drivers/hid/usbhid/usbkbd.c) and [atkbd.c](http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/drivers/input/keyboard/atkbd.c).

Now I am 
confused which of these is the actual code driving my keyboard at the present. As I see it atkbd.c is quite gory and there is a conversion 
of scancodes to keycodes. So it should be the code, though I am not sure.

If atkbd.c is the code, then what is the other code for?

Answer (score 2):

This is easy to check. Let's take usbkbd.c.

The corresponding Kconfig (http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/drivers/hid/usbhid/Kconfig#L50) says:

> Say Y here only if you are absolutely sure that you don't want to use
>   the generic HID driver for your USB keyboard and prefer to use the
>   keyboard in its limited Boot Protocol mode instead.
>
> This is almost certainly not what you want.  This is mostly useful for
>   embedded applications or simple keyboards.

So it looks unlikely to be the keyboard driver we are looking for. Also check current kernel config for `USB_KBD`. The config can be found under `/boot` directory or by running `zcat /proc/config.gz`. If `USB_KBD` is not there, you're not using it. If usbkbd.c is built as module, then will be worth checking if it is actually loaded. Makefile (http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/drivers/hid/usbhid/Makefile#L10) gives the target as `usbkbd`. We can check if it is loaded by grepping for it in output of lsmod.

In contrast, Kconfig (http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/drivers/input/keyboard/Kconfig#L69) for atkbd.c seem much more likely:

> Say Y here if you want to use a standard AT or PS/2 keyboard. Usually
>   you'll need this, unless you have a different type keyboard (USB, ADB
>   or other). This also works for AT and PS/2 keyboards connected over a
>   PS/2 to serial converter.   If unsure, say Y.

Also check kernel config for `KEYBOARD_ATKBD`. If it is Y, you know it is being used. If it's M, check output of `lsmod` for `atkbd`.

Comment: thanks for the answer... So I noted that usb_kbd is 'M' while atkbd is 'Y'. So it's clear that my current driver is atkbd. But you didn't answer my 2nd question. Please elaborate on that part too.

Comment: As it says, it's used for boot protocol. It connects keyboard with minimum initialisation, ie without usb HID

Comment: so I did digging myself, and turns out that usbkbd module is loaded when I insert the external keyboard using usb cable. I disabled 
the usbhid module and no longer the external keyboard was working. But still the laptop keyboard was working. So usbkbd drives the 
external keyboards and atkbd drives the laptop keyboard. Please rephrase as you like this comment and add it to your answer. Then I will accept your answer.

Comment: Good work. usbkdb is gets loaded because it is a _dependency_. The Kconfig quite clear when it reads, "Say Y here only if you are absolutely sure that you _don't_ want to use the generic HID driver for your USB keyboard". The external keyboard uses USB HID to communicate with OS which is why unloading usbhid prevents keyboard from working. It will be worth finding out what's the dependency on usbkbd - `/lib/modules/{kernel-version}/modules.dep` will shed more light on this.